# Server is not responding when single connection is blocked

Tags: nginx, performance, php-fpm, concurrency

I'm not sure how to properly specify this problem, I'm not really a server expert. I will be glad to provide additional data on demand.

I have a PHP web-application running on Ubuntu Server with nginx and PHP-FPM (communicating via socket file). This application talks to another backend server via curl. And I have this one request that is taking a minute to complete. When I hit this request the whole server becomes unresponsive. While this long request is pending no other requests can be completed. When I restart PHP-FPM or this connection dies by itself - all becomes normal again.

I've tried to change some nginx and PHP FPM parameters related to concurrency but to no avail.

### nginx server configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www/example.com/web;

    # removing trailing dot
    if ($http_host ~ "\.$" ) {
        rewrite ^(.*) $scheme://$host$1 permanent;
    }

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to rewrite
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location /js/which.js {
        rewrite . /which.php last;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        # rewrite all to app_dev.php
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app_dev.php/$1 last;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app_dev\.php|which\.php)(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/example.com.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_proxied any;

    gzip_types
        text/plain
        text/css
        application/json
        application/x-javascript
        text/xml
        application/xml
        application/xml+rss
        text/javascript
        application/javascript
        text/x-js
    ;

    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    # Logging configuration.
    error_log /var/www/example.com/var/logs/nginx/error.log info;
}
```

### PHP FPM configuration:

```
[example.com]

user = fpm-example.com
group = fpm-example.com
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/example.com.sock
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 100
pm.start_servers = 10
pm.min_spare_servers = 10
pm.max_spare_servers = 30

request_terminate_timeout = 35s

catch_workers_output = yes

# Logging
php_flag[display_errors] = off
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/www/example.com/var/logs/php-fpm/errors.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: What are the contents of nginx and PHP logs during this situation?

Comment: There are no errors in the logs. All other requests to the server is blocked until this one finishes successfully or dies due to timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, it wasn't actually a server problem. After some additional tests it become apparent that this is the problem with the application itself and not the server. I've created [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25592937/symfony-2-blocked-concurrency) on StackOverflow to narrow down this issue.